# lambda to copy map with different key type

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

We have a `Map<String,MyObject>` which needs to be converted into `Map<Date, MyObject>`.
Here String is nothing but Date stored as String ie,

```
{"1999-11-07T18:30:00.000+0000":{"property1":"value1","property2":valuep1},
{"1998-11-07T18:30:00.000+0000":{"property1":"value2","property2":valuep2}
```

Is there any easy or straight forward way using lambda and streams? We are using java8 and Jackson API.

Comment: I would recommend you move away from `Date` and use `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` as appropriate.  Most of the Date methods are deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yourMap.entrySet().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                this::parseDate,
                                Map.Entry::getValue
                        ));
```

Create a method to parse your String to a date;

```
private Date parseDate(Map.Entry<String, Object> e) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse(e.getKey());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return some date;
    }
```

Comment: Your format string should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`  and the `Map.Entry` should be `<String, Object>` not `<String,String>`